# BitBucket trigger option is not shown in job configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have successfully installed **Bitbucket Plugin** and restart the Jenkins. Wondering why is the option that shows up after adding the plugin not showing up in my Jenkins.

As you can see in the image uploaded. I have  tried everything possible: adding and removing the plugins again but nothing is solving the issue.

[image: no triggering option for bitbucket web hook]

Anyone with similar issue and  have solved it?

Answer (score 1):

hi refer below links for using bitbucket plugin in jenkins.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Plugin

https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/381419546/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket+Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin